# use single recordset in parallel foreach loops SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have multiple (3) foreach loop tasks that i would like to run in parallel using a single recordset
after the recordset is created and the job goes to step into the foreach loops 1 or 2 of the foreach loops throws an error

Error: Variable "User::Site_Recordset" does not contain a valid data object

They are all setup identical as far as the settings for the foreach loop containers using a Foreach ADO Enumerator using my recordset variable as the source and Enumeration mode is set to Rows in the first table.

The processes run fine sequentially but due to the nature of the time it takes to do so i need to process them in parallel. Is this possible to do with a single recordset? do I need multiple copies of the recordset? Is there some type of collision trying to pull from a single recordset?

Any help would be appreciated 
Thank you in advance.

EDIT adding image of plan for clarification
[image]

I would like to be able to run set site schools and set site neighborhoods in paralell this is where i am running into my issue. The recordset comes from the first seq container in the job.

Comment: Could you pop a screenshot of your control flow?

Comment: A recordset can only be read once.  You would need multiple copies of it.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz I think they could be using an outer ForEach loop to enumerate their list once and then using that value to seed 3 ForEach loops

Comment: @billinkc good point!  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: As Mark has pointed out, you cannot re-use a recordset in SSIS. There's no mechanism for putting the pointer back at record zero. Is it possible to restructure your package like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Js1KO.png)?

Comment: A possibility but it still leaves each proc executing in sequence the solution proposed by billinkc will run quicker than doing them in sequence but i think creating multiple recordsets and using them to run in parallel sounds like my best option.